# Why do they put a hole behind some Ganesha idols?

Tags: ganesha, symbolism

I just bought a Ganesha idol from market to my home for Ganesh chaturadhi puja.

I found this **small hole** behind the idol. What does it indicate?

[image]

Comment: That hole might be used for hanging the idol , it may not have any other use or significance IMO.

Comment: Hole is made so that idol can be easily emersed in water. We are celebrating chaturthi today, nd Ther is hole behind d idol ☺